# GNS3 - Emulating a not supported Cisco router (model 881w)

Tags: cisco, router, ios, gns3

I want to create a new configuration for a Cisco 881w from scratch. So I want to replicate my environment on GNS3.

But I cannot emulate a Cisco 881w (which is the router i have) into it. So I am wondering which other router supported by GNS3 should I pick to have the most similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Emulating the lan/wan part of the 881 would be easy with any modular router larger than a 1700.

[2600s](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps259/product_data_sheet0900aecd800fa5be.html), [3600s](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_data_sheet09186a0080091f6f.html) and [3700](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps282/product_data_sheet09186a008009203f.html) can all use the [NM-16ESW](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps259/product_data_sheet09186a00801aca3e.html) module, adding a 16-ports switch to the router. Use only four of them as lan-side of the 881, and one FE port on the chassis (if any) as the 881 WAN port.

The voice and wireless (802.11 or HSPA) parts from the 881 won't be possible to emulate AFAIK.

Piece of warning though: the configuration created on the virtual router will not directly fit in the 881 as the interface numbering scheme will be different.